# Replace all duplicate rows with Nan or blank

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) with different "price"s and I want to compare these prices and make a decision.

`df['Decision'] = np.where((df['price1'] > df['price2']) ,'sell',np.where((df['price1'] < df['price2']),'buy',np.nan))`

My output is:

| price1 | price2 | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 50 | NaN |
| 100 | 200 | buy |
| 70 | 140 | buy |
| 150 | 200 | buy |
| 150 | 50 | sell |
| 60 | 20 | sell |
| 30 | 70 | buy |
| 60 | 100 | buy |

But I want to have just the "first signal" of "buy" or "sell" and **delete replication until the next signal**, as:

| price1 | price2 | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 50 | NaN |
| 100 | 200 | buy |
| 70 | 140 |  |
| 150 | 200 |  |
| 150 | 50 | sell |
| 60 | 20 |  |
| 30 | 70 | buy |
| 60 | 100 |  |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
m = df['Decision'].ne(df['Decision'].shift()) 
df['Decision'] = df['Decision'].where(m, '')
print (df)
   price1  price2 Decision
0      50      50      NaN
1     100     200      buy
2      70     140         
3     150     200         
4     150      50     sell
5      60      20         
6      30      70      buy
7      60     100
```

Or:

```
m = df['Decision'].ne(df['Decision'].shift()) 
df['Decision'] = np.where(m, df['Decision'], '')
```